# How to create flask server stub with either swagger-codegen or openapi-generator?

Tags: swagger, openapi, stub, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I want to generate flask server stub (not API client). The only instructions I found are for swagger-codegen and use java
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#list-of-server-frameworks-supported-by-swagger-codegen-1

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my own solution using provided docker images - simply change `-g` flag for openapi-generator and `-l` flag for swagger-codegen to `python-flask`

```
docker run --rm \
    -v $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i /local/petstore.yaml \
    -g python-flask \
    -o /local/openapi-python

docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli generate \
    -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
    -l python-flask \
    -o /local/swagger-python
```